# "Transport endpoint is not connected" after a few operations?

Tags: mount, ntfs, fuse, ntfs-3g

I set up a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian) as an NAS server and attached a portable HDD to its USB port. File `/etc/fstab` looks like this.

```
/dev/sda1 /mnt/share rw,defaults,nosuid,noexec,nodev,umask=000 0 0
```

When I plug in the HDD **before** powering up the RPi, mount point `/mnt/share` looks OK. But after a few (1-5, variable) R/W operations like `ls` and `cp` (to/from), further operations tell me

```
/mnt/share: Transport endpoint is not connected.
```

`fusermount -u` says not found in `/etc/mtab`???
`sudo umount` gives the same error, only `sudo umount -l` can unmount the filesystem. After re-mounting, the problem remains. Is there a possble solution?

Note: HDD is OK, with only one partition on it. I use `ntfs-3g` and FUSE to mount the drive.

Operations are issued locally from RPi (via SSH), but I don't want to stop `smbd` (or the NAS will make no sense).

Comment: Re-installed a system and set everything up again so the NAS is working for now. The original system is retained so I can reproduce the issue later.

Comment: i'm also seeing this same issue